# linux disabling users from script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am a beginner at scripting but I created a text file called disableusers.dat which contains only usernames that are already created in the file location /home/daniel/var/local/nsu/data and I’m trying to run a script(called disablensuaccounts.sh) that will read the disableusers.dat file that contains a list of users to be disabled. A disabled user’s data will remain on the system but the disabled user account will have no access to login to the system.  For each user account that is disabled, append a line entry to the /home/daniel/var/local/nsu/logs/useraccounts.log file.  The line entry will contain the following information:

```
disabled | <user account name> | <day and time of creation>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
disablefile=/home/daniel/var/local/nsu/data/disableusers.dat
logfiledis=/home/daniel/var/local/nsu/logs/useraccounts.log 
while read user; do
   echo "Disabling $user"
   sudo # passwd -l $user
   echo "disabled | $user | $ date “+%Y-%m-%d %H%M" |" >> $logfiledis
done < $disablefile
```

Comment: I agree with@Mureinik. Your question is unclear. You've figured out one of many ways to disable a user account (`passwd -l $user`), so what's wrong with it, exactly?

Comment: is there any reason for the `#` in the following line: `sudo # passwd -l $user` ?